# A question about Span in Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra

So I have this question about Span that I'm not sure how to do:

Let $\DeclareMathOperator{\Span}{Span}u_1 =\begin{bmatrix}
1\\
2\\
             3    
\end{bmatrix},
u_2 =\begin{bmatrix}
2\\
3\\
4
\end{bmatrix},
v_1 =\begin{bmatrix}
1\\
1\\
2
\end{bmatrix},
v_2 =\begin{bmatrix}
2\\
2\\
3
\end {bmatrix}$, in the real vector space $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Let $U=\Span(u_1,u_2)$ and $V=\Span(v_1, v_2)$.

Show that $U\cap V$ is equal to $\Span(v)$ where $v = \begin{bmatrix}
1\\
1\\
1
\end{bmatrix}$.

So I have already shown that all elements in $V$ can be written as $\begin{bmatrix}
\alpha +2\beta\\
\alpha + 2\beta\\
2\alpha + 3\beta
\end{bmatrix}$ (1)

and that $\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2\\
2 & 3\\
3 & 4
\end{bmatrix}
x = \begin{bmatrix}
\alpha +2\beta\\
\alpha + 2\beta\\
2\alpha + 3\beta
\end{bmatrix}$ only has a solution if $\alpha = \beta$ (2). I have also shown that $\begin{bmatrix}
\alpha +2\beta\\
\alpha + 2\beta\\
2\alpha + 3\beta
\end{bmatrix}$ is equal to $\beta\begin{bmatrix} 
1\\ 
1\\ 
1 
\end{bmatrix} = \beta v$ when $\alpha = \beta$. (3)

I know that I have to show that $U\cap V ⊆ \Span(v)$ and that $\Span(v) ⊆ U\cap V$.

My answer so far:

**$U\cap V ⊆ \Span(v):$**

Since we know that (3) and (2) is true then every element in $V$ can be written as a linear combination of $v$ which means that $V=\Span(v)$. Since $U\cap V⊆ V \Rightarrow U\cap V ⊆ \Span(v)$.

However I'm not sure how to show that $\Span(v) ⊆U\cap V$. Any help would be appreciated!

Edit:

With help from the comments I think I have found the answer:

Since $Span(v)=\{\alpha v|\alpha \in \mathbb{R}\}$ then $\alpha v=\alpha \cdot (−\gamma)\cdot v_1 + \beta \cdot v_2$, where $\beta=−\gamma$ and $\alpha \cdot v=\alpha \cdot (−\gamma)\cdot u_1 + \alpha \cdot \delta \cdot u_2$ where $\delta=−\gamma$ so $Span(v)⊆U\cap V$.

Are both these arguments correct?

Comment: It could be helpful to know the field underlying the vector space.  Is it a vector space over real numbers?

Comment: It is in the real vectorspace $\mathbb{R}^3$. I have added it.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose a vector belongs to the intersection, so it can be written as
$$
\alpha\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \\ 3 \end{bmatrix}
+
\beta\begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ 3 \\ 4 \end{bmatrix}
=
\gamma\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 2 \end{bmatrix}
+
\delta\begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ 2 \\ 3 \end {bmatrix}
$$
Let's then look at the null space of the matrix
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & -1 & -2 \\
2 & 3 & -1 & -2 \\
3 & 4 & -2 & -3
\end{bmatrix}
$$
A standard elimination yields
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & -1 & -2 \\
2 & 3 & -1 & -2 \\
3 & 4 & -2 & -3
\end{bmatrix}
\to
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & -1 & -2 \\
0 & -1 & 1 & 2 \\
0 & -2 & 1 & 3
\end{bmatrix}
\to
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & -1 & -2 \\
0 & 1 & -1 & -2 \\
0 & 0 & -1 & -1
\end{bmatrix}
\to
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & -1 & -2 \\
0 & 1 & -1 & -2 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\to
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & 0 & -1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & -1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\to
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & -1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Thus we get $\alpha=-\delta$, $\beta=\delta$, $\gamma=-\delta$.

Choosing $\delta=1$ and $\gamma=-1$, we get the vector
$$
v=-u_1+u_2=-v_1+v_2=\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}\in U\cap V
$$
The equations imply that the dimension of $U\cap V$ is $1$, so $U\cap V=\operatorname{Span}\{v\}$. If you want a confirm of this, the elimination implies that the rank of $[u_1\ u_2\ v_1\ v_2]$, which equals the rank of $[u_1\ u_2\ {-v_1}\ {-v_2}]$ is $3$ and Grassmann's formula yields $\dim(U\cap V)=\dim U+\dim V-\dim(U+V)=2+2-3=1$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Can you show that $v \in U \cap V$?

Comment: @Javi It's not a critique or a clarification request. It's a hint meant to guide OP to the answer and is fairly standard practice on MSE. See https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28969/is-it-acceptable-to-leave-hints-as-answers

Comment: yes $v = -u_1 + u_2 = -v_1 + v_2$ (egreg also showed this. Not sure how to proceed from here though.

Comment: Ahh so since $Span(v)=\{\alpha v| \alpha \in \mathbb{R}\}$ then $\alpha v = \alpha \cdot (-\gamma) \cdot v_1 + \beta \cdot v_2,$ where $\beta = - \gamma$ and $\alpha v = \alpha \cdot (-\lambda) \cdot u_1 + \alpha \cdot \delta \cdot u_2$ where $\delta = -\lambda$ so $Span(v) ⊆ U\cap V$

Comment: @Nikolaj That's right! More generally, every linear combination of vectors in a span is a vector in the span.